# WYSiHat editing issue

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, wysiwyg, wysihat

I am currently using WYSiHat rich text editor on my java spring project. It works very well, but once I try to edit a pre-made message, the HTML is normally retrieved inside the iFrame, but I can't delete anything out of it unless I add anything inside the message like a space or something.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this issue was also mentioned in this blog post

http://jrmehle.com/2009/02/13/wysiwhat-wysihat-part-2/

From the bottom of that article:

> "After initially being loaded, the editor is “locked” and will not allow you to delete text. This is apparently only an issue in Firefox 3. If you first add something, even a space, it’s refreshes itself or something and you can use delete."

He links to a page I can't get access which apparently refers to the problem. It might be worth double checking if this is the issue you have and maybe look into the issues on github in case a fix is available. I couldn't immediately see the issue in there.

https://github.com/josh/wysihat/issues